How to create Next.js app without Github repository
When I install with 'npx create-next-app@latest', it automatically comes with a git repository already set up. I didn't used to experience this before, but for the past two days, when I create a new project, it automatically sets up its own git with the main branch. What should I do?
I formatted my computer and reinstalled all the installations, but the result did not change.enter image description here

I don't recall having created a next app without a local git repository so it is quite much older than 2 days ago. Furthermore, I don't see the issue with having it set up but, to remove it, just delete the .git directory in the root of your project.

There's no issue with the installation, but I don't want it to automatically add Git when I haven't added it myself. I don't understand why it's doing that. Also, even if I put --no-git, git installs

I don't know all the flags and how they are implemented but, as I said, just delete the folder and you are good.

yes but i want to do it automatically

Send a PR to Vercel. You would need a flag and skip code from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/create-next-app/create-app.ts#L236

The template from next already includes a .git folder.
The flag
"--no-git"
in
"npx create-next-app@latest appName --no-git" (Where appName is optional)
Worked in earlier versions, but it seems like a bug with the flag in current version.
As other people have mentioned, the only workaround until the bug is fixes is to just remove the .git folder.
Everything should work fine after that.
